# Assigning int values to each dictionary entry as well as having reference numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, integer

I'm trying to create a dictionary in python 3 that holds 12 different names, the first 7 must have a value of 8.50, the last 5 13.50
Is it possible to assign them int values? 
I have tried to find answers through google etc but either i'm not wording my questions right or it's not possible. 
At the moment i'm just using:

pizza_dict = {"0: Basic Cheese $8.50", "1: Pepperoni $8.50"}

But I can not find a way to give them int values if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [{}.fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
>>> {}.fromkeys(['1','2','3'],8.5)
{'1': 8.5, '3': 8.5, '2': 8.5}
```

For your example:

```
>>> mydict={}
>>> mydict.update({}.fromkeys(['1','2','3'],8.5))
>>> mydict
{'1': 8.5, '3': 8.5, '2': 8.5}
>>> mydict.update({}.fromkeys(['4', '5', '6'],13.5))
>>> mydict
{'1': 8.5, '3': 8.5, '2': 8.5, '5': 13.5, '4': 13.5, '6': 13.5}
```

Just don't use a mutable argument to do this (like a list) because it is the same one for each key.

Surprising things can happen with mutable:

```
>>> di={}.fromkeys([1,2,3],[])
>>> di[1].append('What?')
>>> di
{1: ['What?'], 2: ['What?'], 3: ['What?']}
```

Comment: Ok thanks but since i'm very new to python I don't have the greatest understanding yet, even with the basics, I'm trying to do things simple as possible and understand each thing I cover it, would something like this work?

pizza_dict = {"0: Basic Cheese $8.50":8.50, "1: Pepperoni $8.50":8.50, "2: Hawaiian $8.50":8.50,"}

Comment: Oh ok I get you now, took me awhile to understand it :) cheers